# Ежедневные уведомления

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Как лучше реализовать ежедневные уведомления?

Т.е. нужно, чтобы приложение посылало сообщение 1 раз в день, в заданное время.

Comment: Вам необходимо отправлять уникальные сообщения, например с сервера? Если нет, то смотрите в сторону [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Вы скорее всего путаете понятие `Push- уведомление`, и `Уведомление`. Push-уведомление - это инициация сервером каких-либо действий на стороне клиента. Не имеет отношения к визуализации чего либо. Уведомление - информация в строке состояния Android.

Comment: @metalurgus да, Вы правы. перепутал.

Comment: @miha_dev да, спасибо, видимо `setInexactRepeating` и `setRepeating` - то, что надо. сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Смотрите код в вопросе по ссылке выше вместе с исправлением ошибки в нём, коя разъяснена в ответе.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 0k, спасиб0.

Answer (score -2):

набросайте простой скриптик, посадите его на крон...

```
15 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

это запустит скрипт в 0:15 каждый день :-)

**P.S.** а этот скрипт уже пусть уже запускает Ваше приложение

Comment: В Android нет cron

Comment: нет, это не вариант.